# How to repeat the request until receiving a certain answer?

Tags: javascript, json, testing, postman

I need to write code that will iterate over the query until the desired result. For example, I send a request:

```
{{API host}}/{{APP ID}}/{{REST API}}/hive/Management/set/keys?filterPattern=*&pageSize=5&cursor=0
```

The server returns:

```
{
    "keys": [],
    "cursor": "252"
}
```

I intercept the `cursor="252"` value and add it to the next query

```
{{API host}}/{{APP ID}}/{{REST API}}/hive/Management/set/keys?filterPattern=*&pageSize=5&cursor=252
```

This should be repeated until the server returns `cursor="0"`

Help me solve this problem, I've been scratching my head for 4 days and I'm out of ideas. Maybe it can be solved with the help of a `while` loop? Help

Answer (score 0):

The option I found for myself:

```
const res = pm.response.json();

if(res.cursor !== "0"){
    postman.setNextRequest("Your Request")
    pm.test('Cursor is not equals 0', () => {
        pm.expect(res.cursor, 'Error').to.not.eql("0")
    })
} else {
pm.test('Cursor equals ' + res.cursor, () => {
    pm.expect(res.cursor).to.eql("0")
})
}
```

Hope this helps someone